# Jquery - Unable to Remove DIV

Tags: jquery, html

Im trying to remove a div that has been inserted by my previous Jquery code.

```
$counter = 0;
$("#add").click(function() {
    $counter++;
    $("#ipblock").append('<input type="text" name="inputip" id="inputip'+$counter+'" size="22" /></br>');
});

$("#del").click(function() {
    $("#inputip'+$counter+'").remove();
    $counter = parseFloat(counter) - 1;
});
```

The full demo can be found here http://jsfiddle.net/felix001/fQBNE/26/ . 
I can see via firebug that the inputs have the correct id`s. But when I try to remove it in both jquery and via the firebug console it fails to find the div (??).

Any one able to point me in the right direction.

Thanks,

Comment: Make sure your selector is correct for the remove:
`$("#inputip'+$counter+'")` should be `$("#inputip"+$counter)`. On JSFiddle it was removing them for me once I changed it, but it was still glitchy.

Answer (score 2):

You've got a couple errors in your code:

```
$counter = 0;
$("#add").click(function() {
    $counter++;

    //I removed the `<br />` tag and added a bit of CSS because if you remove the <input /> tags the <br /> tags added with them remain
    $("#ipblock").append('<input type="text" name="inputip" id="inputip'+$counter+'" size="22" />');
});

$("#del").click(function() {

    //this just makes sure there is actually an element to select before trying to select it
    if ($counter) {

        //use double quotes to start and stop the string here
        $("#inputip"+$counter).remove();

        //make sure to refer to `$counter` and not `counter`
        $counter = $counter - 1;
    }
});​
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fQBNE/29/

I added this CSS so that the `<br />` tag wasn't necessary in your `.append()` call:

```
/*This will put each input on its own line*/
#ipblock > input {
    display:block;
}​
```

## Update

Another way to accomplish this without a `$counter` variable is to select the last `input` element in the `#del` click event handler:

```
$("#add").click(function() {

    //notice no ID is needed
    $("#ipblock").append('<input type="text" name="inputip" size="22" />');
});

$("#del").click(function() {

    //first try to select the last inputip element
    var $ele = $('#ipblock').children('input[name="inputip"]').last();

    //only proceed if an element has been selected
    if ($ele.length) {

        //and now remove the element
        $ele.remove();
    }
});​
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fQBNE/31/

Comment: ah cool. The jsfiddle just shows a 404 ? But I like the different method of doing it. One thing whilst doing this that Im unsure of is the different ways to create a variable.
In this example we use "$counter = 0;" but in another fiddle I created I used "var REGEX = /^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$/;". Thanks again.